# ERC20 Reference on separate contract

Tags: erc-20

How can I reference the balanceOf function and transfer function of an erc20 token represented by a separate ERC20 contract?

So little time, so much to know! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare the token contract in your own contract using the IERC20 interface with `IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenContractAddress)`
Then you can interact with it using
`uint256 balanceOfUser = token.balanceOf(address)` <- this stores the balance of `address` in `balanceOfUser`
`token.transfer(address, amount)` <- this transfers `amount` from the contract to `address`
`token.transferFrom(address, address(this), amount)` <- this transfers `amount` of tokens from the user to the contract.
Generally the way to interact with a contract through an interface is `Interface contract = Interface(contractAddress)` <- declaring
`contract.function(param1, param2)` <- interacting